# Apostrophe (') in BibTeX not visible after compilation?

Tags: bibtex

I have a BibTeX item as follows.

```
@inproceedings{Orsdemir2008,
    Author = {Orsdemir, A. and Altun, H. and Sharma, G. and Bocko, M.},
    Booktitle = {Proc. IEEE MILCOM’ 08},
    Month = {Nov},
    Pages = {1-7},
    Title = {On the security and robustness of encryption via compressed sensing},
    Year = {2008}}
```

I am under `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}` and invoke the reference part by

```
{\footnotesize
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{myBibFile}}
```

I then get this as the result.

> [10] A. Orsdemir, H. Altun, G. Sharma, and M. Bocko, “On the security
>   and robustness of encryption via compressed sensing,” in Proc. IEEE
>   MILCOM 08, Nov 2008, pp. 1–7.

As you may have found out, the `'` just after `MILCOM` is missing. How may I fix this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The "apostrophe" character in your code is *not* an [ASCII single quote](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=%27) (`'`), i.e. the character of hexadecimal ASCII code 27, but a [Unicode "right single quotation mark"](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=U%2B2019) (`’`), i.e. the Unicode character of codepoint U+2019. Once you've noticed that, the problem should become clear, because [BibTeX does not support Unicode characters](http://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Tips#encoding) (sorry, it's the best link I could find).

I'm guessing you probably copied that BibTeX entry from somewhere on the Internet and then pasted it into your `bib` file, and the ASCII single quote got lost in the process... if it ever was in the original BibTeX entry to begin with!

Simply replace the Unicode character in question by an ASCII single quote. After running `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, and then `pdflatex` twice, you should get:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{IEEEtran}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @inproceedings{Orsdemir2008,
        Author = {Orsdemir, A. and Altun, H. and Sharma, G. and Bocko, M.},
        Booktitle = {Proc. IEEE MILCOM '08},
        Month = {Nov},
        Pages = {1-7},
        Title = {On the security and robustness of encryption via compressed sensing},
        Year = {2008}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Text \cite{Orsdemir2008}.

{\footnotesize
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{\jobname}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good catch - must have switched it over when I moved it from `MILCOM'` to `'08`...

Comment: @cslstr Yes, I guess. To be fair, it's easy to miss.

Comment: So...I use Biber, which *does* support Unicode *bib files. Same problem, however. Any ideas what might be happening there?