# Apostrophe ending a word sticks to next word

Tags: bibtex, unicode, apostrophe

The title of a work I have to cite has a word ending with an apostrophe. Given [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168146/apostrophe-in-bibtex-not-visible-after-compilation), I'm using the ASCII single quote (`'`) to write the entry, but this generates the following problem:

[image: citation with word ending in apostrophe, stuck to next word]

As you can see, the words "managers'" and "prior" are stuck. I checked how this article is cited on Google Scholars. To my surprise, they use the Unicode "right single quotation mark" (`’`). I used it in my `.bib` file and it worked!

[image: citation with word ending in apostrophe, no longer stuck to next word]

Why does this happen?

Thanks in advance.

```
@article{sandor01_conjoint,
title   = "Designing conjoint choice experiments using managers' prior beliefs",
author  = "Zsolt Sándor and Michel Wedel",
year    = "2001",
journal = "Journal of Marketing Research",
volume  = "38",
number  = "4",
pages   = "430--444"
}

@article{sandor01_conjoint,
title   = "Designing conjoint choice experiments using managers’ prior beliefs",
author  = "Zsolt Sándor and Michel Wedel",
year    = "2001",
journal = "Journal of Marketing Research",
volume  = "38",
number  = "4",
pages   = "430--444"
}
```

Edit: I add a MWE. The packages that fix the language to spanish are mandaroty, because the references have to be in spanish (e.g. Name Surname y Name Surname instead of Name Surname and Name Surname).

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage[activeacute,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}
\selectbiblanguage{spanish}

\begin{document}

Hello world \cite{sandor01_conjoint}

\bibliographystyle{babalpha-fl}
\bibliography{bibliografia}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add a minimal example of LaTeX code?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.  Currently nobody can reproduce your output without a lot of effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `activeacute` option: if you use UTF-8 you don't need it.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test1,
title   = "Designing conjoint choice experiments using managers' prior beliefs",
author  = "Zsolt Sándor and Michel Wedel",
year    = "2001",
journal = "Journal of Marketing Research",
volume  = "38",
number  = "4",
pages   = "430--444"
}

@article{test2,
title   = "Designing conjoint choice experiments using managers’ prior beliefs",
author  = "Zsolt Sándor and Michel Wedel",
year    = "2001",
journal = "Journal of Marketing Research",
volume  = "38",
number  = "4",
pages   = "430--444"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}
\selectbiblanguage{spanish}

\begin{document}

Hello world \cite{test1} and \cite{test2}

\bibliographystyle{babalpha-fl}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The `filecontents*` environment is used just to make the example self-contained and not clobber my files.

[image]

If you really need `activeacute`, type in the apostrophe as

```
Designing conjoint choice experiments using managers'{} prior beliefs
```

Comment: Whoa! I never thought `activeacute` could cause this issue. As I understand, the option allows me to write accents using the `\'a` format to obtain `á`. Now that I think about it, given that I use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, `activeacute` is no longer necessary.

Comment: @IgnacioCorrea The option allows you to type `'a` (without backslash) to get `á`. You can still type `\'a` without the option, if you prefer.

Comment: You're right, but as a native spanish speaker, it is much more comfortable to type `á` right away than `'a` or `\'a`, because of grammar checks and the like. Thank you for your answer and comment!

Answer (score 2):

Various things like `managers{'} prior` did not work, but `managers'\ prior` did work.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage[activeacute,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}
\selectbiblanguage{spanish}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bibliografia.bib}
@article{sandor01_conjoint,
title   = "Designing conjoint choice experiments using managers'\ prior beliefs",
author  = "Zsolt Sándor and Michel Wedel",
year    = "2001",
journal = "Journal of Marketing Research",
volume  = "38",
number  = "4",
pages   = "430--444"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

Hello world \cite{sandor01_conjoint}

\bibliographystyle{babalpha-fl}
\bibliography{bibliografia}

\end{document}
```

[image]